# Drives not shown on a Dell r410 server

Tags: linux, dell, dell-perc, dell-poweredge

I have just bought a Dell R410 server, without doing research first.

It seems that with the current RAID controller (perc s300) I can't install a GNU/Linux system. It supports only Windows.

After removing the controller and connecting the drives (SATA HDD) directly to the main board with a SATA cable they are not shown at all. BIOS doesn't see them.

I just upgraded to the latest BIOS version from 1.3.9 to 1.11.0, but still no progress.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Dell servers have an option that enables/disables the SATA ports on the motherboard. Go into the BIOS and enable them if you're going to bypass the RAID card.

Manual page: http://www.manualslib.com/manual/37060/Dell-Poweredge-R410.html?page=62

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried that. HDD are shown as "unknown".